# How can you reduce disconnects from Android apps using server sent events?

Tags: android

I use an Android app that on a bad time,  every few seconds to a minute disconnects from the server for 15-16 seconds in which time download speed remains under 1KB/s. I am pretty sure it must be something to do with server sent events, but I have no idea what can be done on my end to make this less frequent. Any suggestions?

Comment: There can be many reasons for that. I would look at network issues first.

Comment: Sorry if my question was dumb, I'v only got a couple of 1st year uni programming papers and some dabbling on my own to work off, so I don't know how feasible what I'm looking for is

Comment: I have had lagg on other apps before but this is the only 1 with discovering issues,  does that rule out network issues?

Comment: Any speed test I take while the app causing issues is not loaded has 8-10MB/s download, 3MB/s upload, 150 ping. This is going to the same country as the apps main server. Mabe the ping that's the problem?

Comment: can you add code from the client? also what is on the server side (node.js, nginx)?

Comment: No idea how to tell